# Calling twice a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

What I would like to do is calculate the value of a coordinate in the pascal triangle, I got a table with **X and Y axis** where I have my pascal triangle aligned at the top and the left, what I'm trying to do is to create a function to return the value in a specific point [ for example (3,2) = 2 ] 
Here's what I've tried:

```
var getCalc = function value( x, y ) {

    if( y == 0 || y == x ){
        return 1;
    }

    return value(x - 1, y - 1) + value(x - 1, y);
}
```

Here's the table with the pascal triangle:

[image]
What we got here is a recursive function called twice in the last return, when executing it I get the following error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Also I would like to know how could I do it using ES6

Comment: I just did and it's working fine...

Comment: What makes you think ES6 would be any different?

Comment: Please re-evaluate my updated answer.

Comment: in your function you have a typo: if you see in image - x,y values starts from 1, so in your function just change `if( y == 0` to `if( y == 1`. And you get right result

Comment: What arguments are you calling it with? `getCalc(3, 2)` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

And `getCalc(3,2) = 3`
//this function is wrong

Please take a look at [this implementation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#JavaScript) of printing Pascal's triangle:

```
getCalc(3,2)
-> getCalc(2,1) + getCalc(2,2)
   ->getCalc(1,0) + getCalc(1,1) + 1
      ->1 +1 +1= 3
```

Snippet to build the entire triangle:

```js
function pascalRecursive(n, a) {

  if (n < 2) return a; // We already have the top row

  var prevTier = a[a.length-1];
  var curTier = [1];

  for (var i = 1; i < prevTier.length; i++) {
    curTier[i] = prevTier[i] + prevTier[i-1];
  }
  curTier.push(1);
  a.push(curTier);

  return pascalRecursive(n-1, a);
}
var triangle = pascalRecursive(100, [[1]]);
alert(triangle[1]);
///sum
alert(triangle[1].reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0))
```

Comment: Hmm, if it works then it's not generating the right numbers, what should I do to get (3,2) = 2? That's the real value in the pascal triangle

Comment: I just tested, if the output **isn't the expected**, so your code is wrong... please keep studying and read the reference mentioned on the answer...

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is mostly ECMAScript, and you're doing anything that violates the version 6 specification but you can [lint here](http://www.jslint.com/).

- your [pascal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle) table looks like it's for rows not the standard diagonals (this answer deals with diagonals but provides a non-diagonals example at the end if that's what you want).
- Your code should be run through a beautifier.
- There is no need to make 2 functions (getCalc, and value)
- when y == x the result should not always be 1
- you are summing the wrong boxes (x - 1, y - 1) is up like a square not a triangle (x, y - 1)

The corrected function:

```
var value = function(x, y) {
    if (y == 0 || x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return value(x - 1, y) + value(x, y - 1);
};
```

Also you could still get "call stack size exceeded" with really big numbers or invalid numbers, a safety wrapper might look like this:

```
var safeValue = function(x, y) {
    if (x > 20 || y > 20 || y < 0 || x < 0 || Math.floor(x) != x || Math.floor(y) != y ) {
        return null;
    }
    return value(x, y);
};
```

If you use the web developer tools in any browser to make a break point you can track each recursion and what all the variables are.
You can add a depth variable to track how many recursions occurred.

Output [verification](http://www.sfu.ca/~rpyke/335/projects/ching/number_theory.htm):

```
(-1,0)=null
(0,0)=1
(2,3)=10
(2.5,3)=null
```

Like most recursion you can also express this as a loop, and the depth limitation is greatly reduced.

```
var value2 = function(x, y) {
    var xp;
    var yp;
    var theArray = {};
    for (xp = 0; xp <= x; xp += 1) {
        for (yp = 0; yp <= y; yp += 1) {
            if (xp === 0 || yp === 0) {
                if (!theArray[xp]) {
                    theArray[xp] = {};
                }
                theArray[xp][yp] = 1;
            } else {
                if (!theArray[xp]) {
                    theArray[xp] = {};
                }
                theArray[xp][yp] = theArray[xp - 1][yp] + theArray[xp][yp - 1];
                //memory saving step
                if (theArray[xp - 1][yp]) {
                    delete theArray[xp - 1][yp];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return theArray[x][y];
};
```

As you can see from the timing tests it makes a huge difference:

```
var a=new Date().getTime();console.log(value(13,13));console.log('time='+(new Date().getTime()-a));
10400600
time=4526

var a=new Date().getTime();console.log(value2(13,13));console.log('time='+(new Date().getTime()-a));
10400600
time=0
```

So having taken the function from [O(n^n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) memory to O(n), there is a function that will use O(n) time instead of O(n*n);

```
var value3 = function(x, y) {
    var sum = 0;
    var tmp;
    var xp;
    for (xp = 0; xp <= x; xp += 1) {
        if (xp === 0) {
            tmp = 1;
        } else {
            tmp = (y + xp) / xp;
        }
        if (sum === 0) {
            sum = tmp;
        } else {
            sum = sum * tmp;
        }
    }
    return sum;
};
```

again the timing difference is huge;

```
var a=new Date().getTime();console.log(value2(500,500));console.log('time='+(new Date().getTime()-a));
2.702882409454366e+299
time=24

var a=new Date().getTime();console.log(value3(500,500));console.log('time='+(new Date().getTime()-a));
2.7028824094543663e+299
time=0
```

Or if you want non-diagonal rows:

```
var value4 = function(x, y) {
    if (y < x) {
        return null;
    }
    var sum = 0;
    var tmp;
    var xp;
    for (xp = 0; xp <= x; xp += 1) {
        if (xp === 0) {
            tmp = 1;
        } else {
            tmp = (y - (xp - 1)) / xp;
        }
        if (sum === 0) {
            sum = tmp;
        } else {
            sum = sum * tmp;
        }
    }
    return sum;
};
```

Comment: I updated the post with an image of the table I mention, the coordinates I mentioned are the table row and column

Comment: it's only partially tail recursion.

Comment: What you mean?, if I use your code I don't get the value positioned at (6,8) = 21 for example

Comment: @user5429739 see the "Or if you want non-diagonal rows" section.